# Out of sync Artifactory metadata.xml

Tags: maven, artifactory

Can somebody explain how the versioning of the maven metadata xml file in Artifactory works

According to the snapshot info 8.1.7-20140515.144329-35 is the latest build. Though version is 4 builds behind (2 days old) 8.1.7-20140513.105115-31

If it was a caching issue I would have expected the rest of the versions to be behind as well.

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.foo.backoffice</groupId>
  <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.7-20140513.105115-31</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
        <timestamp>20140515.144329</timestamp>
        <buildNumber>35</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20140515151522</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>tgz</extension>
            <value>8.1.7-20140515.144329-35</value>
            <updated>20140515144329</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>pom</extension>
            <value>8.1.7-20140515.144329-35</value>
            <updated>20140515144329</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>tgz</extension>
            <value>8.1.7-20140515.144329-35</value>
            <updated>20140515144329</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>rpm</classifier>
            <extension>rpm</extension>
            <value>8.1.7-20140515.144329-35</value>
            <updated>20140515144329</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>manifest</classifier>
            <extension>xml</extension>
            <value>8.1.7-20140515.144329-35</value>
            <updated>20140515144329</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
        <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>static</classifier>
            <extension>tgz</extension>
            <value>8.1.7-20140515.144329-35</value>
            <updated>20140515144329</updated>
        </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
</versioning>
```

Comment: It appears that version corresponds to the first snapshot for that version. Though that makes no sense whatsoever. I found this by deleting the first snapshot and looking at the metadata and it updates to the next snapshot.